# Difference in integral character heights

Tags: front-end, formatting

[image]

Above is an example of what happens. It seems that the first integral is longer than the second because the y-character is longer than the x-character as this doesn't happen with other similar-height characters:

[image]

Is there a way to change this so that the integral defaults to the larger size regardless of whether x or y is used?

If it's any help: the stylesheet is **Outline** and the screen environment is **bulleted**.

**Edit** - In response to the comments, this was in a text cell (part of a set of math notes)

**Edit** - By default it is in TraditionalForm. Converting to StandardForm, then back to TraditionalForm makes them look the ideal way:

[image]

Comment: This is just another example showing, alas, that Matheamtica is not an ideal medium in which to _typeset_ mathematics. As contrasted with (La)TeX.

Comment: This seems to be system-specific. I cannot reproduce this on MacOSX.

Comment: I can reproduce this under MacOSX, 8.0.4.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, Mathematica shrinks down typesetting that involves scripts and stretching inside of inline cells.  The principle is to try to not introduce too much bulky whitespace as a result of the extra height of the typesetting.  I suspect that the small scale at which things are operating is making it more sensitive (perhaps wrongly so) to differences of a pixel or two.

Perhaps you'd just rather have the extra space to get nice, large typesetting.  That's really easy to do.  In your notebook, choose the menu item:

Format->Edit Stylesheet...

In the resulting notebook, paste the following cell:

```
Cell[StyleData["InlineCell"], ScriptLevel->0]
```

You might have to save/close/reopen the notebook to get this change to trigger.  Once you do, the change will affect all inline cells in your notebook.

Comment: Yep. This did the trick. Incidentally, it solved another problem I was having - that typing "lim" and then trying to add an underscript would default to a subscript. After implementing your solution, that's been fixed as well.

Comment: @user745434 Yeah, in addition to limits, `ScriptLevel` also affects the positioning of Subsuperscript, such as you see in definite integrals, and Underoverscript, such as you see in sums and products.

Answer (score 6):

This only seems to happen in Inline Cells at certain magnification levels (or font sizes).

Input cell:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As above but in an inline cell:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The same inline cell but with a different Magnification level:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I don't have a complete fix but this might at least help you work around the problem.

Would you consider having the integral symbol be a fixed but short size a solution?

---

On a second look I think there is an actual bug involved.
Here is the inline cell at 55% and 50% magnification:

[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]

Notice that at the *lower* magnification the left $\int$ actually *grows* while the right one shrinks.

I can think of no valid explanation for this behavior.

Comment: This is probably a bug, although I haven't done the due diligence to determine exactly what's going on (and, honestly, I probably won't for a while...sorry).

Comment: @JohnFultz Thanks.